# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'

Tags: build, failed-installation

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/Users/vivekmandal/Downloads/Stock app/_codecanyon_main_files/signally-main/signally_flutter/android/app/build.gradle' line: 74
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> path may not be null or empty string. path='null'

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                            3.8s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
vivekmandal@Viveks-MacBook-Air signally_flutter %